# Cannot retrieve button on the bottom of the page

Tags: protractor

In my protractor test, I have a button on the bottom of the page. This button only visible when I go down the page.

So, when I'm running the test it gives an error message telling cannot find the element and test fails.

Tried to add `browser.driver.sleep(500);` but didn't help.

Any help would be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to add a scroll down to your code.

```
browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(0,0);').then(function () {
    page.saveButton.click();
})
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thank u so much for the tip. :)